# How can I add print-safe areas, also known as margins, when rendering a PDF via ImageRenderer in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm looking for a way to include print-safe areas, also known as margins, in my PDF between pages during rendering. Here is my code, which currently renders a multi-page PDF without margins between pages.

```
    static func render(view: some View) -> URL {
        
        // 1: Render View with some modifiers
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: view)
        let url = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "output.pdf")
        
        
        // 2: Start the rendering process
        renderer.render { size, context in
            // 3: Tell SwiftUI our PDF should be the same size as the views we're rendering
            var box = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 612, height: 792) // Letter size in points
            
            // 4: Calculate how many pages we need
            let pageCount = Int(ceil(size.height / box.height))
            
            guard let pdf = CGContext(url as CFURL, mediaBox: &box, nil) else {
                return
            }
            
            // Split the view into pages
            // Iterrate over the pages and render them
            
            for page in (0..<pageCount).reversed() {
                
                
                let offset = CGFloat(page) * box.height
                
                // 5: Start a new PDF page
                pdf.beginPDFPage(nil)
                
                
                //6. write chopped view to the page
                pdf.translateBy(x: 0, y: -offset)
                
                
                
                // 7: Render the SwiftUI view data onto the page
                context(pdf)
                
                // 8: End the page and close the file
                pdf.endPDFPage()
            }
            
            
            pdf.closePDF()
        }
        
        return url
    }
```

I searched through numerous examples, YouTube videos, and Apple documentation.

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of playing with x and y values?

Comment: @ElTomato No, it doesn't work as intended. The entire view is rendered as one piece. If you adjust the Y values, it will add margins at the beginning and end of the PDF file, rather than between pages.